# How to get the number of notifications when the application is minimized? Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

The app detects the number of notifications i can download. How can I get this number of notifications when the application is minimized? in Xamarin. Sorry for the short question but i have no idea in this technology

Comment: What type of notification do you use? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: currently I want to do it on the widget, added a dot with xml and it reads the number of notifications. My code: https://stackoverflow.com/.../how-do-i-set-the-widget-to.... I've used https://github.com/wcoder/ShortcutBadger before but it doesn't work on all phones

Comment: Sorry,I couldn't open the first link you posted. In addition, could you please  the detail about this problem (`but it doesn't work on all phones`).